# Oracle JDK 7 with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: 12.04, java, eclipse, maven-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

I know this has been asked many times but I just recently switched to linux and I'm having a hard time piecing everything together.

I have Oracle's JDK 7 running just fine from the command prompt but I'm not sure what the best way to install eclipse and maven are so that they will use it.

Last time I tried installing eclipse with apt-get and it ended up installing openjdk6.

How do I go about installing eclipse and maven so that they both are using oracle 7 jdk?

Thanks!

Comment: there are more than one questions here... please edit it to ask just one.

Comment: I started a chat room to talk about your problem if you want.  It's here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3496/oracle-eclipse-discussion

Answer (score 2):

Pre question edit:

You need to:

- [Install the Oracle JDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)
- [Install portable eclipse(I would recommend sticking with the openJDK and eclipse from repo in order to avoid known bugs with unity and java software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)
- [Add the maven snap-in for eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49557/how-do-i-install-maven-3)

I think it's a duplicate question, but you combine multiple questions into one.  This violates the ask one question at a time component of [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq).

Post question edit:
You would need to look at the questions on installing eclipse and set your launcher to use a terminal so your .bashrc variables get applied.  An alternate solution would be to set up the environment variables in .profile. A better alternative is to use update alternatives, but this too is covered in the oracle-jdk question.

It's my opinion that it's still a duplicate despite having narrowed scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to avoid installation of `default-jdk` in Ubuntu 12.04 i.e `openjdk6`
`$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not set the path correctly

After installing openjdk set the path to the oracle jdk...

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH

This is taken for [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Answer (score 0):

you can also get it from the ubuntu software centre, and you can also use openjdk6 or 7, you can easily install that with synaptic software centre (sudo apt-get install synaptic)
I got eclipse running just fine.