# Ubuntu adding path/Environment variables

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, environment-variables, maven-3

I am trying to install apache maven 3 in Ubuntu 12.04 lts. What I did was open the terminal then I typed the following commands

- export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.5 [Then pressed Enter]
- export M2=$M2_HOME/bin [Then pressed Enter]
- export PATH=$M2:$PATH [Then pressed Enter]

After that I typed

```
mvn --version
```

and it displayed all the necessary information but after closing the terminal, again I typed the command `mvn --version`

then it said that 'mvn' is not recognized

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try sudo apt-get install <selected-page>
```

is there a way to permanently add a PATH variable in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Add those `export` lines to your `~/.profile` file.

If you want it to apply to all users on the system, put it in `/etc/profile` instead;

```
sudoedit /etc/profile
```

Once you've edited either, you'll see the effect next time you log in.

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

On a side-note, if you instead install maven via the software center or `apt-get`, you won't need to do any of the above.

Comment: I tried the apt-get but it is the old version. I am using 12.04 lts. anyways where would I place it here? I already tried sudoedit /etc/profile but i have no idea where to place it here

Comment: @user962206, You can put them at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to add the environment variable permanently. 
Use the following command, for editing the file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Then use this command, to source it:

```
source /etc/environment
```

[Reference](http://lukieb.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/installing-maven-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server/) - Installing Maven 3 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server

Comment: "`$source`" is no command